# How to correctly implement Java Instrumentation interface?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jar, manifest

I am trying to estimate the memory of some objects for a project and I want to use the getObjectSize() method from the instrumentation interface. I've been following the steps on how to create an Instrumentation agent from these two websites ([https://iq.opengenus.org/find-size-of-an-object-in-java/](https://stackoverflow.com) and [https://www.baeldung.com/java-size-of-object](https://stackoverflow.com)). However, when I try to make an agent JAR with a custom manifest File, it returns this error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)`.

This is the full command and error: I've also taken a screenshot of where the files and difrectories are in the project. I made a separate project folder to try to get the Instrumentation interface to work.  [Screenshot of Project layout on IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DedKt.png)

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro objectTesting % jar -cfm Sizeof.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF Sizeof.class                
java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:158)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:278)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.j
```

I thought initially that it was because I put the manifest file and META_INF folder in the wrong place, but it still returned the error after I moved it around a few times. How do I fix this? Also, how would I implement the Instrumentation interface into my other projects once I get it to work?

Alternatively, are there any other ways to estimate the memory consumption of an object in Java?

Comment: What “instrumentation interface” did you mean? JMX?

Comment: According to your screenshot, the entry to add to the jar would be `org/example/InstrumentationAgent.class`, not `Sizeof.class`. The current directory must be the folder to which IntelliJ stores the compiled class files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in actual memory / CPU consumption of a program, use a profiler like [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to see how it behaves and look for any performance hotspots.

If you're actually interested in object/class size for micro-optimization purposes, then [JOL](https://github.com/openjdk/jol) can size your objects without running an agent and comes even with an Idea plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:  You don't want instrumentation, even if you do, you can't implement it, messing with the manifest won't accomplish what you want (but if it does - that's not how you use `jar`).

In some more detail:

Your title and your question have nothing to do with each other. It sounds like perhaps this is what happened:

- You are attempting to write an agent so that you get an impl of `Instrumentation` so you can do instrumentation things.
- You failed at the job.
- You decided to just abort what you were doing entirely and are now thinking: Eh, maybe I'll just implement `Instrumentation` on my own! ... how do I do that? Better ask SO.

You don't implement `Instrumentation`. You can't. The JVM implements it and hands you an implementation. That answers the question in your title.

> jar -cfm Sizeof.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF Sizeof.class

That's not how jar works. This command says:

- Please make a new jar (`-c`).
- Please name this jar `Sizeof.jar (`-f Sizeof.jar`)
- Please put a manifest in it by copying a text file. This text file can be found, relative to the current dir, at this place (`-m META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`).
- Please put file `Sizeof.class` in the jar.

You're confused about what `-m` does. The argument (you passed `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`) has to be to **an actual text file already existing on disk**. It's not 'where the manifest goes' - that goes at META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, **period** - it can't be anywhere else, hence, there is no need to tell `jar` where to put it - it already knows. You **do** need to tell `jar` what to put **in** the manifest. `-m` is one way to do that, and you pass a text file.

So, you need to MAKE a manifest file. Get an editor out, make a text file, stick this in it:

```
Agent-Main: com.foo.packagename.of.YourAgentMainClass
```

call it 'agent-manifest.txt'.

Then run:

```
jar -cfm Sizeof.jar agent-manifest.txt com/foo/packagename/of/YourAgentMainClass.class
```

Then run a java app, pass the jar the above command produces as agent, and now your `agentmain` method (that has to be in the class `YourAgentMainClass` which is in package `com.foo.packagename.of`) will be executed, and handed an instance of `Instrumentation`.

Note that agents aren't java apps - they are JVM plugins: You run **another** java app, and the agent can for example replace bytecode.

If you just want to check how large some object is in a java app, `Instrumentation` just isn't the answer. I don't know what is, but that isn't it. More generally "I want to know how large this is" isn't a question the JVM is good at answering - the usual solution is not to ask it. Why do you need to know? There may be an entirely different way to fulfill whatever requirement needs to know.

NB: Putting `main` classes in the default package is a bad idea. Don't do that - make an actual package.